# how to dismount the USB which connected on remote machine using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, wmi, device-manager

I have tried:

1. [deviceIoControl function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) but I think this cannot work for
   remote machine [(my sample code)](https://godbolt.org/z/TEdMzrMvv)
2. [dismount function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/dismount-method-in-class-win32-volume) in WMI but it  mount again as auto-mount is
   true when I tried to false the automount that function return
   [mountpoint is available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/dismount-method-in-class-win32-volume#return-value) error,So How can I **delete mount point in remote machine.**
3. disabling the USB mass storage driver in device manager can dismount
   the USB,but can   not access the device manager in remote machine
   that has windows 8 and after release version [click here to see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/error-connect-device-manager-remotely#cause)
4. i am going to try [CM_Request_Device_EjectA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_request_device_ejecta) but to
   connect with remote machine [CM_Connect_MachineA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_connect_machinea#parameters) cannot
   applied for windows 8 and after release version

I don't know what to do next.I want to do this **without mostly setup or configure on remote machine.**

Comment: write a program that runs on the other machine and does it?

Comment: Which is exactly what I said 2 days ago on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679016/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau ,To execute the program using namedpipe function in remote machine, I have to connected with that pipe,To connect with that pipe I have to create the pipe on remote machine,here is the problem , that I should not create any pipe in remote machine. So,Is there any default created pipe listening for connection that I can use ?

Comment: @NaveenCS no, there is not. You will have to run your own software on the remote machine, and have it open some type of communication channel that you can then connect to (named pipe, socket, etc)

Comment: @Jeaninez - MSFT how to connect using CM_CONNECT_MACHINE function

Comment: @NaveenCS Accoring to the Doc: [CM_Connect_MachineW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_connect_machinew) Beginning in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 functionality to access remote machines has been removed. You cannot access remote machines when running on these versions of Windows.